# Is there a way to pass a value from a mysql callback function to the outer function in express?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I'm using express and npm MySQL to develop an API.I have a json request in this format:

```
 {
    "payments":[
        {
            "PolicyNo": "ME3",
            "PaymentDate": "2019-04-16T18:00:00.000Z",

        },
            {
            "PolicyNo": "PIN001q",
            "PaymentDate": "2019-04-16T18:00:00.000Z",

        }]

}
```

I want to check the database if the policyNo exists before inserting. To avoid the common ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT, I've looped through the payments querying the database with the PolicyNo. If it exists it's pushed into a success array if it doesn't it's pushed into a failed array.
This works perfectly but I can't access these arrays outside the callback.
Here's what I've tried:

```
router.post('/bla', (req, res)=>{
const values = []
const failedvalues = []
let sql = 'SELECT PolicyNo from pinclientinfo WHERE PolicyNo=?'
req.body.payments.forEach(element => {

    connection.query(sql,element.PolicyNo,(err, rows) =>{
        if(!err){
            if(rows && rows.length > 0){
                values.push(element.PolicyNo, element.PaymentDate)
            }else{
                failedvalues.push(element.PolicyNo)
            }
        }
    })

})

res.json({
    failed:failedvalues,
    success:values
       })
})
```

Here's the response I'm getting:

```
{
"failed": [],
"success": []
}
```

Comment: Async await?? have you tried promisifying the mysql query?

Comment: No, I'm not using promises, just callbacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has some major problems, mostly conceptually.

Firstly the `forEach` is synchronous will be called `payments.length` number of times, but the sql query is Asynchronous so it will complete in the future.

I think you are confused between synchronous and asynchronous functions and how they work.

But you can solve this (in your case) atleast two ways.

1) Use the IN syntax and get the array. Iterate over it and do stuff. `"SELECT PolicyNo from pinclientinfo WHERE PolicyNo in (...)"`

```
let sql = 'SELECT PolicyNo from pinclientinfo WHERE PolicyNo IN (' + Array(req.body.payments).fill('?').join(',') + ')'

const policies = req.body.payments.map(p => p.PolicyNo);
const values = [];
const failedvalues = [];
connection.query(sql, ...policies, (err, rows) => {
    //now check each row..
    rows.forEach(element => {
        //Not optimized only depicts logic
        ///do stuff
        /// like fill values and failedvalues
        if(policies.indexOf(element.PolicyNo) > -1){
            values.push(...)
        }else{
            failedvalues.push(...)
        }
    });

    res.json({
        failed: failedvalues,
        success: values
    })
})
```

Which will be 1 DB call.

2) The other approach is (not very good) doing multiple db calls and check for count.

```
let sql = 'SELECT PolicyNo from pinclientinfo WHERE PolicyNo=?'
let count = 0;
req.body.payments.forEach(element => {
    connection.query(sql, element.PolicyNo, (err, rows) => {
        if (!err) {
            if (rows && rows.length > 0) {
                values.push(element.PolicyNo, element.PaymentDate)
            } else {
                failedvalues.push(element.PolicyNo)
            }
        }
        // check If all Complete
        count+=1;
        if(count === req.body.payments){
            //all complete
            res.json({
                failed: failedvalues,
                success: values
            })
        }
    })
})
```

**BUT SERIOUSLY, USE `PROMISE`. USE `ASYNC/AWAIT` USE THOSE SWEET LITTLE FEATURES ES6 GIVES YOU**

Check out: [this post](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/javascript-from-callbacks-to-async-await-1cc090ddad99)

Comment: I had tried your approach previously. The problem with it is there's no way to get the success or failed arrays, only a response with the existing policies will be retrieved

Comment: If you check for the `PolicyNo` in the rows, if it exists push to `values` otherwise push to `failedvalues`.

Comment: The post you've shared really helped. I'm using promises now

Answer (score 0):

because connection.query is asynchronous, so return:

```
{
  "failed": [],
  "success": []
}
```

use `promise` and `await` you can synchronized resolve mysql data

use `Promise.all()` you can synchronized resolve list of promise

```
router.post("/bla", async (req, res) => {
  let values = [];
  let failedvalues;

  let promises = [];

  let sql = "SELECT PolicyNo from pinclientinfo WHERE PolicyNo=?";
  req.body.payments.forEach(element => {
    promises.push(
      new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        connection.query(sql, element.PolicyNo, (err, rows) => {
          if (!err) {
            if (rows && rows.length > 0) {
              values.push(element.PolicyNo, element.PaymentDate);
            } else {
              failedvalues.push(element.PolicyNo);
            }
          }

          resolve();
        });
      })
    );
  });

  await Promise.all(promises);

  res.json({
    failed: failedvalues,
    success: values
  });
});
```

Comment: this will most certainly not work. Because the promise will be resolved after just 1 query. don't you think so?

Comment: This works!! I'm definitely taking a dive into promises. Normal callbacks are so limiting